# magento 's cookie time not the same to timezone

Tags: magento, cookies, timezone

I have searched for more than two hours, my problem is:

I need to use cookies but I found my magento's cookie time is not right.
I have reinstalled my magento and in the `system/configuration/general/locale` options choose my timezone.

But when I went to my website, I found the cookies time still using GMT and the Path is not right too..(and they are magento's cookies "frontend" and "adminhtml", not the cookies I set, since I need to fix the cookie time first and them start to work on my own cookies).

But I use `<?php echo Mage::getModel('core/date')->date();?>` in the header.phtml to print my time, and this time is right.

So it means the place which set the cookies don't use the timezone.

Comment: Which version of Magento? You can check in *./app/Mage.php*

Answer (score 2):

And are you sure that the settings haven't been set at a lower configuration scope (website or store level)? Use the GUI tool in upper left corner of **System > Configuration** screen or use a query:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data`
WHERE `scope` != 'default'
  AND `path` LIKE 'web/cookie%';
```

If you get any results for the above query, there are values set at the store or website level.

Comment: I went to phpmysql and in the SQL I run your qurey the result is MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0007 sec )  and my configuration scope set in default the lower level is use default.what should I do~~~~~  i will continue work on it untill I fix this or I can't go on my work...